# Importing multiple modules causes build to fail - C2664

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am experimenting with C++20 modules, and I have run into an error I don't know how to fix.

See the following module file(VClipTypes.ixx):

```
module;

#include <vector>

export module VClipTypes;

export class Vec3
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
export class ClipVertex
{
public:
    Vec3 _point;
};


export class ClipMesh
{
public:
    std::vector<ClipVertex> _vertices;
};
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
import VClipTypes;    

int main()
{

    ClipMesh m;
    m._vertices.push_back(Vec3());
    std::cout << "mesh vert count: " <<m._vertices.size()<< std::endl;
}
```

In this form, the code compiles and runs normally, with output "1", as expected.

However, if I move the Vec3 class into it's own module interface(Vector.ixx)

```
module;
export module Vector;

export class Vec3
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

And then add an `import Vector;` statment to both VClipTypes.ixx and main.cpp, then the build fails with the following error:

```
Error   C2664   'void std::vector<ClipVertex,std::allocator<ClipVertex>>::push_back(const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Vec3' to 'const _Ty &'
```

It looks to me like something has gone with the vector template instantiation, but I can't be sure. I'm sure I've done something wrong somewhere, but I can't see where.

Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: The bug is the opposite of what you think: you shouldn’t be able to pass a `Vec3` here ever.  `emplace_back` would work, though, since you can direct-initialize aggregates in C++20.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I am using the latest version of MSVC.

Comment: @Davis Herring: could you put this in an answer, explaining what you mean please?